# Is it possible to install Rocks Cluster Distribution on Raspberry Pi?

Tags: pi-3, linux, cluster

There are lots of websites about making a supercomputer with Raspberry Pi. Is it possible to install "Rocks Cluster Distribution" on Raspberry to have a more efficient cluster?

Comment: Quoting the Rocks "getting Started" (http://www.rocksclusters.org/rocks-documentation/4.1/getting-started.html), "Rocks supports all the hardware components that RedHat supports, but only supports the x86, x86_64 and IA-64 architectures.". Unsure if this means for just the head node or all the nodes... I too am looking for an answer.

Answer (score 3):

No, it is not.  No ARM support and Centos 6 was latest build.